# Undo --no-restore in R

Tags: r, workspace

During the installation process I have set R to not restore the workspace and now want to undo this - 
how is it done?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Austria.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Austria.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Austria.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Austria.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If you are using `RGui` from a windows shortcut, edit the short cut to remove the `--no-restore` flag.
- If you are using R through, `Rstudio`, look under Tools-->Options-->General and select the appropriate option
- For other IDEs there should be similar ways to set start-up options.

The other option would be to reinstall `R` the way you would like it to be done.

Comment: I re-installed R since I didn't find another solution (the windows shortcut had no -no--restore flag).